# Counting table entries that are not numeric in views

Tags: views

I have a table view which lists names of hotels in column A and in columns B-D I have columns that contain scores for 'location' 'room cleanliness' and other things. These particular fields are made up of text lists with the following reviews:

'no mention'
'positive'
'negative'

and are made up of Check boxes/radio buttons

What I want to know is how to count all the reviews up ('no mentions' 'positives' and
'negatives')

at the bottom of each column. I can't use Views Calc or aggregation as these are not numeric entries. It also seems extremely long winded to create a view for each scoring thing ('location', 'room cleanliness') then add a filter to each one with negative, positive etc etc

Does anyone know the best way to do this or if indeed I have set the fields up correctly?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I encourage you to use evaluate/rating modules like [fivestar](https://drupal.org/project/fivestar) that support a [voting API](https://drupal.org/project/votingapi) that make life easier. This way you reuse a tested code (less probability of bugs) and you can find suppport easily. An bu the way, they make the calculation.

Comment: Hi, good idea. I have used fivestar before actually. Question is, will it count my columns up though? I understand it rates individual nodes, I need to rate 'fields on nodes' as I have around 5 fields that all have three options. I was also thinking about the flag module as well, maybe this might also do the job.